# How to use a map in a java customobject for firestore

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Java customobject that I use in Firestore to set a product.

It looks partly like this:

```
package product.firebaseobjects;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Product {

private List<String> productcodes;
private Map<String, String> altdescriptions;
private String description;
private Long amount;
private boolean hasimage;
public Product(){
}

public FBProduct(List<String> productcodes, Map<String, String> altdescriptions, String description, Long amount, boolean hasimage) {
    this.productcodes = productcodes;
    this.altdescriptions = altdescriptions;
    this.description = description;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.hasimage = hasimage;
}
(getters & setters omitted)
```

Retrieving is done using

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(PRODUCTS).document(id);
ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
DocumentSnapshot document = null;
Product product = null;
try {
    document = future.get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (document.exists()) {
    product = document.toObject(Product.class);
}
return product;
```

When I save this object using this code

```
List<string> productcodes = new ArrayList<>();
productcodes.add("productcode1");
productcodes.add("productcode2");
Map<String, String> alt = new HashMap<>();
alt.put("French","French description");
alt.put("German","German description");
String description = "Description";
Long amount = 1L;
boolean hasimage = false;
Product product = new Product(productcodes, alt, description, amount, hasimage);

ApiFuture<DocumentReference> future = db.collection(PRODUCTS).add(product);
```

all fields are saved to Firestore except for the field 'altdescriptions'. This field is not to be found. All examples in the docs use `Map<String, Object>` which i tried as wel but does not make a difference.

From searching I found solutions that use the update() method using dot notation, but then you are not using the customobject.

My question is, how to use a Map in a Firestore Java customobject. And if that is not possible, what is the preferred way of setting, updating and retrieving Maps for a customobject.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are using to create the `product` object that is passed to `.add(product)`. Please also show us the constructor of your `Product` class.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Please also share the code where you assign values to the fields, including `altdescriptions` property.

Comment: I have added that code.

Comment: If you try to check the value of `altdescriptions` before writing data to the database, do you get the correct value?